# navbar ul li display becomes block after resize

Tags: html, css

I'm making navbar and I don't want my ul li to ever become block even after resize, I wrote this code but when i convert my browser to mobile or resize and make it smaller it becomes block any solutions ?

```css
#intro .nav ul{
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top:15px;
}
#intro .nav ul li{
  font-family: 'Baloo Tammudu 2',cursive;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-right:155px;
  font-size:2em;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
      <div id="intro">
        <div class="nav">
          <ul>
              <li class="about">
                <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="shop">
                  <a href="#">shop now</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="feedback">
                    <a href="#">feedback</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: The problem is not inside the code you provided.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D when my browser is on the full screen those `li`s are normallry inline but after I convert my browser into mobile it's not inline anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fixed "width" in your navbar. or you can use "min-width". otherwise, it's never possible.
example:

```
#intro .nav{
  min-width:900px;
}
```